# Logic Programming: Solve the term constraint f(X; Y; g(a)) = f(g(Y ); Z; X)

Tags: prolog, constraints, unification

I was not able to attend my programming language class the other day due to my wonderful car crapping out on me. I am working on our homework assignment, I am doing pretty good till I got to this scary looking question:

```
"5. Solve the term constraint f(X; Y; g(a)) = f(g(Y ); Z; X). Show steps."
```

Now, I have read the slides, but I cannot make out what he is trying to say (He is from China)
and he does an awful job of explaining things.

I was wondering if any of you kind folks would be able to show me how to solve a problem similar to this one. Explain it as if I am a five year old.

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:** I was in the wrong section on the lecture notes, I found this:

- Any term constraint is processed in the following way

• **Case 1**: itis of formc1=c2 where c1 and c2 are constants
– If c1 isidentical identicalto c2, discard discard it; otherwise otherwise report no solution solution

• **Case 2**: it is of form x=t1 (x is variable and t1 a term)
– Assign t1 to x, discard this constraint, and replace all x in allterm
constraints by t1 ift1 has no x inside it; otherwise report no
sol iuton

• **Case 3**: itis ofthe formf(s1,…,sn) = g(t1,…,tn)(f,g:
function symbols,si and ti:terms)
– If fisidentical identicalto g,replace replace the termconstraint constraint by constraints constraints

*s1=t1 and s2=t2,……,sn=tn; otherwise: no solution*

– Repeat this process until no more constraints left or a
report of no‐solution solution exists.

It is not quit clear to me yet, I am going to keep reading over it till it does. I'll post back what I think the solution is, maybe one of you can tell me if I got it right.

Comment: Use the Martelli-Montanari algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f(X; Y; g(a)) = f(g(Y ); Z; X).
```

Your first step is to notice that `f/3` = `f/3`, which is case 3. Case 3 will succeed if X=g(Y), Y=Z, and g(a) = X.

Then `X=g(Y)` might trivially be true; let's replace X with g(Y) in both sides:

```
f(g(Y); Y; g(a)) = f(g(Y); Z; g(y))
```

OK, moving along let's unify Y with Z. I don't see a case for this.

```
f(g(Y); Y; g(a)) = f(g(Y); Y; g(Y))
```

Moving along, the next thing we have is `g(a) = g(Y)`. This succeeds unifying Y=a. The resultant term is:

```
f(g(a); a; g(a)) = f(g(a); a; g(a))
```

which is looks obvious. X = g(a), Y = Z = a.

I have no idea if this is right, but that's my guess.

Comment: Wow thanks for the response, that is very clear to me. I briefly read over your post, not enough where I memorized each step, but enough to understand what you doing and I am going to give it a whack. Thanks!

Comment: `f(X; Y; g(a))` is of the form `f/1` (not `f/3`): you can see this easily with: `?- write_canonical(f(X; Y; g(a))).`, yielding: `f(;(_,;(_,g(a))))`.

Comment: @mat You're 13 months late. Thanks a billion.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons: Your response will certainly be read more often in the future than it has been in the past. Thus, the correction for future readers.